# Excel- Find and mark latest date per patient

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to find the latest visit date/time per unique patient id and insert Yes/No in a new separate column.  Patient number is unique, but the date/time stamp can be the same across different patients.

[image: Patient chart]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula if the data in the date column is a real date/time.

To test if it is a real date/time value and not just text, select the column and format as "General". If that changes the values to numbers, then you're good to go. If the dates don't change, then you will need to convert the text to date/time values first.

Once you have real date/time values in that column, you can use a formula along these lines:

```
=IF(B1=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A1),"yes","no")
```

This formula uses MaxIfs() which is only available in Office 365 versions of Excel. If you have an older version, you can use the following formula, which must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter and you don't want to use whole column references.

```
=IF(B1=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$10=A1,$B$1:$B$10)),"yes","no")
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Sir / Madam ,
If Patient ID is in Column A, and Time is in Column B then select the data

1. Go to Sort
2. First Level Sort On Column A, Order Ascending.
3. Select Second Level Sort On Column B, (Time), Sort on Descending Order.

This will give the view, as per requirement

After this You can Enter : Yes, No.

Thanks.

Comment: ... and then you need to delete the yes/not and repeat the process again and again and again when new data is added ....

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use a pivot table. This only shows the latest date, you'll have to go back to your data and filter if you are interested in looking at patient visit history. Here's the initial setup:

[image]

Then change the number format to date and remove the grand total row to get:

[image]